# iOS SwiftUI - Binding custom array error: Unexpected initializer in pattern; did you mean to use '='?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I need to pass an array to a view:

```
@Binding var memes: [MemeModel]()
```

I get the error

```
Unexpected initializer in pattern; did you mean to use '='?
```

why and how to fix this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[MemeModel]()` is an initialized, empty array of `MemeModel`s. Try deleting the `()` to indicate the type (rather than provide an actual object). Depending on what else is going on in the code, you may need to write `@Binding var memes = [MemeModel]()` to actually assign something to this variable (note that here, the type is implicitly specified).

Comment: Ok works, thanks for the explanation! Will accept asap